# How can I update and insert into two different tables using php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update  a particular table using mysql database with an output message in the php script using echo and at the same time and insert into another with a redirection after a successfully insertion.
Here is what I have tried but not getting the result I wanted

```
<?php
$dbhost="xxxx";
$dbusr="xxxx";
$dbpass="xxxx";
$database="xxxxx";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusr,$dbpass, $database);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("databse not connected");
$num = rand(98564654, 415231564); 
If(isset($_POST['login'])){
$Pin=$_GET['pin'];
$ID =$_POST['ID'];
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if($Pin!=''){


mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num', status='Activated' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO pinlog (TableName,pin,id,TIME_UPDATED) VALUES('Pin','$Pin','$num','$date')")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

header("location:applicantlogin.php");
}
}

?>
```

Please Help

Comment: Don't put your DB password in your question next time. ^_^ Also stop using `mysql` as it has officially been deprecated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would specify a question. This is mainly a question & answer site.

Comment: The script keep on updating table over and over whenever i try to activate pin again. I want it to activate only once. If already activated it should echo already activated.

Comment: Just do as you say : `if (already activated in database) { echo 'already activated' } else { //update }` where `already activated in database` is a select query...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

First, set PIN activated only when its not activated:

```
UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num', status='Activated'
    WHERE Pin= '$Pin' AND status <> 'Activated'
```

Then, find out how many rows were affected (there's a function for that).
If 0 then already activated and bail out. Check your indexes as well.